# columnfigure in windows, doesn;t work as expected

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

I tried to make 12 columns with minimum 60 pixel size. But, all buttons are gone. `signup` button in first column, `login` in third column.

```
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("1280x720")
clientFrame = tkinter.Frame(root)

signupBtn = ttk.Button(clientFrame, text= "Signup")
signupBtn.grid(column= 0, row= 0)

loginBtn = ttk.Button(clientFrame, text= "Login")
loginBtn.grid(column= 2, row=0)

clientFrame.columnconfigure(list(range(12)), minsize=60)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call `pack() / grid() / place()` on `clientFrame`.

Try adding:

```
clientFrame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
```

Comment: lol, what a stupid. why i dont think it. i just follow tutorial. i dont see tutorial put grid in the end after configure. thank you, you save alot time.